# Open Source Secure Sockets Framework

Tags: frameworks, protocols

I am looking for an open source framework to build a proprietary protocol onto (Agent/Client talks to a Receiver/Server that stuffs things into a SQL database).
I need session handling (ie login/logout) and some kind of encryption.
I found the Spread Framework which looks great, but does not appear to support authentication or encryption of any kind out of the box.
My preferred language is C, C++, Python, or Perl.
Anyone know of anything off hand? Hoping for something to be out there to save me time rather than doing it the hard way all in *nix sockets ;)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Definitely trying to write an application from the ground up.
A server that utilizes asynchronous IO (non blocking IO) to support many concurrent connections.

Comment: This looks just what I need http://www.bigspeed.net/index.php?page=bssocklib
But I really would prefer an open source solution. Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use libcurl, as it can do SSL.
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Answer (score 0):

[DJango](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and DJango ORM, or [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) combinations can be a good start. A python base framework and ORM.

Comment: How do these help the OP with secure sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working at the socket level, I assume that you are trying to write an application from the ground up.  Or are you trying to run within an existing web server?

Could you use lighttpd with HTTPS & mod_cgi?  This isn't really a framework, per se, but it would keep your application portable to other infrastructures.

On the server side, [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/) could take care of the session management.  Authentication could be done using [mod_auth](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModAuth).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SSL/TLS?  On the client you can use libcurl, which works with C, C++, Python, and Perl.  On the server, use Apache, lightttp etc, with cgi or your favorite language.  You can  use mutual authentication to ensure verify the identify of both the client and server, as well as provided an encrypted channel.